# How to pass function using react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know we can pass value through route by `state`:

`<Link  state ={someItem:""}/>`

or use `useNavigation()`

```
const nav = useNavigation()
const navTo =  () =>{
   nav("somePage",{state:{someItem:""}}
}
```

But whenever i try to pass function like

```
const [state1,setState1] = useState('')
```

And i pass through state
`<Link  state ={function:()=>{setState(123)}}/>`

It will always return null

```
{
    "pathname": "/search",
    "search": "",
    "hash": "",
    "state": null,
    "key": "default"
}
```

So my question is how to pass function through react-router (V6)

Comment: Route state needs to serializable. Functions are not. What is the total use case you are trying to solve for?

Answer (score 0):

**How now to pass value to components?!**

```
    <Route exact path='/component' render={() => <myComponent prop={value}/>} />
```

**How to make it that when loading it goes directly to the '/component' page, and not to '/'?!**

```
<Redirect exact from='/' to='/component'/>
```